# custom view with custom text view

Tags: swift, textview

I created a custom view, in that custom view is a text view. The text view is meant to be populated with posts from firebase. Sometimes the posts can be really lengthy and not fully fit the text view/custom view. I want to manipulate the length of the custom view so that the custom view expands based on how much words are in the text view. [image]
There is a label "Comments" at the bottom of the view that should also move down if the post is too lengthy 
[image]

```
PostEntry.text = Content
    PostEntry.frame.size.width = 344
    PostEntry.sizeToFit()


    PostComment.frame.origin.y = PostEntry.frame.maxY + 20
    NewView.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text view to size to your text is actually quite simple. You set the desired width of the text view, and the content, and then ask it to size itself:

```
myTextView.text = "Some really long text..."
myTextView.frame.size.width = 200
myTextView.sizeToFit()
```

And the view will adjust it's size to fit your content for the given width.

Now your custom view can simply layout the "Comments" label below that

```
commentsLabel.frame.origin.y = myTextView.frame.maxY + 20
```

Comment: how would i do that to also increase the height of the custom view

Comment: In your custom view you probably then want to override `sizeToFit` to adjust it's height to fit the new height of your content. Then whatever "owns" this view can ask it ti size itself during layout.